# Badge Progress Bar

Tags: feature-request

Is there anyway to see how your badge progress is, I mean for example if you have edited 500 posts, you will be awarded with a badge, but can i see my current number of edited posts? and so many other status like this. I couldn't find any thing regarding to this and i think it would be very helpful to have a Progress bar for every badge that shows us where we are.

Comment: You might also want to check out [We don't need no stinking badges](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge/).

Comment: Is there any way to turn off badges? I'd include tags if I could, but I've already learned to ignore them. But badges clutter up the landscape and intrude on discussions; it's not like they mean anything or have any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some badges (custodian, reviewer, steward, civic duty, copy editor and electorate) there is a progress bar available.

To find your progress for a particular custodian, reviewer or steward badge:

1. go to the [list of review queues](https://english.stackexchange.com/review)
2. pick one of the queues
3. go to the stats tab of that queue (e.g. [close vote stats](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats))
4. at the top you can see a progress bar: [image: progress bar for cose votes]
5. hover you mouse over the progress bar and you will see your progress towards the next badge in the set.

This will also show you your progress towards the civic duty, copy editor and electorate badges, regardless which review queue you pick.

[image: progress bars for badges]

For tag badges, you can work out your progress from your profile. For a bronze tag badge, for example, you need to have

> a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

If you look at the tags section of your profile, it will tell you your stats regarding this. A breakdown of non-wiki Question vs Answer votes can be found by hovering over the vote total for a tag:

[image: vote breakdown for SWRs]

You can see your progress towards the fanatic badge at your profile, too. It tells you how many consecutive days you have visited the site. The same can be said about the Marshal badge.

Some badges don't really require a progress meter (e.g. constable or sheriff), but for badges that are earned on votes, views or favourites you can see the progress without a bar (just order your posts by votes, views or favourites), and since these can be earned multiple times what would a progress bar show?

There are a few badges that can't easily be tracked, but I think that's nice because then, if you earn them, you get a nice surprise.